# How would I solve this in a way to allow my database to be firstly populated by woocommerce and then allow myself to make whatever changes I wish?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an e commerce mobile app using React Native, within this I have a server, the role of the server is currently to get products from the woocommerce APi, take only the fields I need : name, id, category,price, image and then add another field called 'favourite'(for my wishlist).

Everything was worked well until the getProducts method has a method that calls the woocommerce API and then pushes that to the database. Problem is that whenever I try to update an item to 'true' rather than 'false' within the favourite field. It populates but when I refresh the page which also recalls the API, it brings the 'favourite' field back to false, which it was initially initialised as in the server.

I present the code in question:

```
app.get("/getProductsForUser", async (req, res) => {
    const productDetails = {};
    const numberOfProducts = 25;
    api
    .get("products", {
      per_page: numberOfProducts, // 20 products per page
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // Successful request

      var key = "Products";
      productDetails[key] = [];
      var data;

      for (let index = 0; index < numberOfProducts; index++) {
        productDetails[key].push({
          id: response.data[index].id,
          name: response.data[index].name,
          image: response.data[index].images[0].src,
          price: response.data[index].price,
          favourite: false,
          category: response.data[index].categories[0].name,
        });
      }
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(req.query.userID)
        .collection("products")
        .doc("0")
        .set({ productDetails });

      res.send(productDetails);
    })

    .catch((error) => {
      // Invalid request, for 4xx and 5xx statuses
      console.log("Response Status:", error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // Always executed.
    });
});
```

If there is a way I can only call the above function once in the whole project (which is in nodejs by the way) and then after that only call from the database, that will help?

Answer (score 0):

Just get your stored product in the DB before you push the product to the list: something like :

```
for (let index = 0; index < numberOfProducts; index++) {
   const storedProduct = db.collection("products").getByID(response.data[index].id);
   productDetails[key].push({
      id: response.data[index].id,
      name: response.data[index].name,
      image: response.data[index].images[0].src,
      price: response.data[index].price,
      favourite: storedProduct.favourite ,
      category: response.data[index].categories[0].name,
});
}
```

so instead of setting it always to false set it to the stored value.

You could also implement it in a different way. where you don't have to get the products every time for the woocommerce API. to provide you with such a solution I will need more context to your application. for example, do you have a way to run timely triggered scripts? or is it possible to call the  woocommerce API somewhere else and store the results in the DB so you don't need to call it every time the you have a call to /getProductsForUser